# How to properly do centered zooming?

Tags: c, zooming

My problem is more generic than programming, however it involves some basic C codes, I hope this won't be closed in here.

I have a rounded target display, which will display an image, first centered and fitted:

[image]

Circle's radius is 360, that's fixed.

I need to add do zoom-in and out functionality (in case image is larger than target). In this example the above image is `1282x720`, so it's well above the circle's size. (To fit into the circle, now it's roughly `313x176`)

I would like to do a properly aligned "center-fixed zoom", i.e.: whatever is currently centered shall remain centered after the zoom operation.

Image is put into a component called *scroller* which has an option to set its *offset*, i.e. how many pixels shall it skip from top and left of its content. This scroller component is by default aligns its content to top-left corner.

I've put a red dot into the middle of the image, to be easier to follow.

So upon zooming in this happens (image is starting to be left-aligned):

[image]

Please note it is still in the middle vertically, as it's stills smaller in height than its container.

However on the next zooming-in step, the red centerpoint will slightly go downwards, as the image in this case has more height than container, hence it's also started being top-aligned:

[image]

Now, making it to stay always in center is easy:

I need to ask the scroller to scroll to

```
image_width/2 - 180, //horizontal skip
image_height/2 - 180 //vertical skip
```

In this case, if I zoom-in in 5 steps from fitted size to full size, scroller's skip numbers are these:

```
Step0 (fit): 0, 0 
Step1: 73, 0
Step2: 170, 16
Step3: 267, 71
Step4: 364, 125
Step5 (original size): 461, 180
```

But I don't want the image to stay in center constantly, I'd rather do something similar what image editors are doing, i.e.: center point shall remain in center during zoom operation, than user can pan, and next zoom operation will keep the new center point in center.

How shall I do this?

Target language is C, and there is no additional 3rd party library which is usable, I'll need to do this manually.

Scroller is actually an *[elm_scroller](https://docs.enlightenment.org/elementary/1.15.0/group__Scroller.html)*.

Comment: I think this is a really interesting question however unfortunately I think it's quite a bit vague without some context of what language you're programming in. For example, C# WPF has this boiled doing to a pretty simple `ScaleTransform`, where you can tell it scale factors and define a center point (e.g. X=50%, Y=50%). Python might require some 3rd party imaging libraries and some manual code as you described. In C would obviously be a bit more challenging for a less experienced programmer because it would require implementing even basic concepts like the idea of a center point, etc.

Comment: Language is C, I'll add it. And there is no usable library, I have to calculate it manually.

Comment: Could you also post an example or mockup of what `scroller` is? And do you have the ability change that control's code? This will very likely change how people provide answers and feedback.

Comment: Scroller is actually an `elm_scroller`, basically it's nothing just a container which expands with its content and makes it "scrollable" with scrollbars.

Comment: This one seems not good. Let's consider only the width: in original case to be centered: `1282` is width and `461` is offset. One size smaller: `1088` width and `364` offset. Calculation of the scale: `1088/1282 ~ 0.8487`. Calculation of new offset: `0.8487*461 ~ 391`. And not 364.

Comment: It sounds like you need an improved linear transform, but I'm not familiar with a scroller. @Aelarion is right, it would help to post some code that uses the scroller, even if it doesn't currently do what you want.

Comment: @Daniel you're definitely right my comment was bad and misleading so I deleted it, probably while you were commenting. My bad, I just didn't want to leave it up to possibly confuse other people reading.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify all four positions points, not only x2 and y2, think of them as a the sides of a rectangle, so to keep a centered zoom every side of the square needs to "grow" to de absolute center of the image.

- X1 > Left , Y1 > Top
- X2 > Right , Y2 > Bottom

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {

    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
    int32_t width;
    int32_t heigth;

    uint32_t o_width;
    uint32_t o_heigth;

} IMG_C_POS;

void set_img_c_pos(IMG_C_POS * co, int32_t w, int32_t h){
    co->o_heigth = h;
    co->o_width = w;
    co->heigth = h;
    co->width = w;
    co->x = 0;
    co->y = 0;
}

void add_img_zoom(IMG_C_POS * co, uint16_t zoom){
    uint32_t zoom_y = (co->o_heigth / 100) * (zoom / 2);
    uint32_t zoom_x = (co->o_width / 100) * (zoom / 2);
    co->heigth -= zoom_y;
    co->width -= zoom_x;
    co->x += zoom_x;
    co->y += zoom_y;
}

void sub_img_zoom(IMG_C_POS * co, uint16_t zoom){
    uint32_t zoom_y = (co->o_heigth / 100) * (zoom / 2);
    uint32_t zoom_x = (co->o_width / 100) * (zoom / 2);
    co->heigth += zoom_y;
    co->width += zoom_x;
    co->x -= zoom_x;
    co->y -= zoom_y;
}

void img_new_center(IMG_C_POS * co, int16_t nx, int16_t ny){
    int32_t oy = co->o_heigth / 2;
    if(oy <= ny){
        co->heigth += oy - ny;
        co->y += oy - ny;
    } else {
        co->heigth -= oy - ny;
        co->y -= oy - ny;
    }
    int32_t ox = co->o_width / 2;
    if(ox <= nx){
        co->width += ox - nx;
        co->x += ox - nx;
    } else {
        co->width -= ox - nx;
        co->x -= ox - nx;
    }
}

void offset_img_center(IMG_C_POS * co, int16_t x_offset, int16_t y_offset){
    if (y_offset != 0){
        int32_t y_m_size = (co->o_heigth / 100) * y_offset;
        co->heigth += y_m_size;
        co->y += y_m_size;
    }
    if (x_offset != 0){
        int32_t x_m_size = (co->o_width / 100) * x_offset;
        co->width += x_m_size;
        co->x += x_m_size;
    }
}


int main(void) {
    
    IMG_C_POS position;
    set_img_c_pos(&position, 1282, 720);

    sub_img_zoom(&position, 50);
    img_new_center(&position, (1282 / 2) - 300, (720 / 2) + 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("X1 -> %-5i Y1 -> %-5i X2 -> %-5i Y2 -> %-5i \n", 
        position.x, position.y, position.width, position.heigth
        );

        offset_img_center(&position, 4, -2);
        add_img_zoom(&position, 20);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx. One small addition: my image's original size is 1282x720, and to fit this image into the desired circle I had to zoom-out. It is not an exact 20%, because it depends on image's aspect ratio. So I need to start with zoomed out image fits the circle. Then I'd like to have 5 steps reaching the original size and keeping the center. However, I'd also like to keep the center (the current one, not the red point!) if user panned the image, is this solution able to do that as well?

Comment: Yes, to move the center you just need to add or remove to de axis (x1 and x2 or y1 and y2), I've added 2 extra functions to move the center, you can change the % to px, its fine if you want. The numbers i used are for testing that it works, you will need to find out what works for you and with witch values.